# "tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:" is getting call instead of "tableView: objectValueForTableColumn: row:" for cell based tableView

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nstableview

I am using both cell based and view based NSTableView in AppDelegate class. Both method `"tableView: objectValueForTableColumn: row:" and  "tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:"` is present in this class. For both the table `"tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:"` is getting call. if i am commenting `"tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:"` method then `"tableView: objectValueForTableColumn: row:"` is getting call for cell based table. What may be the issues? how to resolve this?

Comment: if i am commenting "tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:" then "tableView: objectValueForTableColumn: row:" is getting call for viewBased Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to switch the cell-based table view to be view-based or you need to use separate delegates.

The set of methods implemented by the delegate in part determines whether the table view is actually view-based or cell-based. So, you can't really use the same delegate for both.

Note, for example, that there's no way to set whether a programmatically-created table view is view-based or cell-based. It's determined entirely by the delegate. Well, it seems that even for table views created in IB, where it is possible to set that, the delegate still partially determines the type of the table view.

On the other hand, even view-based table views call `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`, so I'm not sure why it's not being called in your case. Maybe when the delegate does not provide any cell view, the table view just doesn't bother.